# Regular expression for processing European numbers and vice versa

Tags: javascript, regular-language

I am trying to find a simple way of working with numbers in my app that works with European numbers, which is turning out to be more complicated than I thought. According to the European number format, thousand separators are denoted by a period (.) and decimals places in comma (,), and the number operators in Javascript gets confused, and try to interpret 1000 (writen as 1.000) as 1, and the users, who are Europeans, get confused by regular number expressions...Currently I am using a simple regular expression to remove the period from the number so it renders properly

```
(/\./g, '')
```

But as you can imagine, this solution only works if there are no decimal places. What would be a regular expression to remove any thousand separators, if they exist, AND if there is a separator at in front of the last two digits, replace it as a decimal separator, and then convert and display the number back to the user in its original format?

Comment: can u provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: For example, 5.000 after (/\./g, '') will be treated as 5000, but 5000,98 with the same expression turns into an error. To convert 5000 back to 5.000, I can use an expression like .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "."), but again, nothing would happen to the decimals

Comment: how you knows that 5000 equals 5.000 and not 50,00 ??

Comment: Well that's also the problem. Basically, as long as an European user follows the European convention and either not put any thousand separator, or use a period as the separator and only enters integers will have the numbers displayed correctly, but doing anything else will immediately cause the number to be misinterpreted.

Answer (score 0):

If that style is consistent u can map the dots to empty strings and the commas to decimal vales, for example:

```
const values = ['5000,98', '5.000']

const parseEuropeanNumber = string => Number.parseFloat(string.replace('.', '').replace(',', '.'))

const parsedValues = values.map(parseEuropeanNumber)

console.log(parsedValues)
>>> [ 5000.98,5000 ]

const sum = parsedValues.reduce((acc, currentVal) => acc + currentVal, 0)

console.log(sum)
>>> 10000.98
```

Comment: Thank you. I modified the idea a bit since I realized all I have to do is to switch the commas and periods around, and then remove the period for rendering. To format it for the computer: .replace(/[,.]/g, function (x) { return x == "," ? "." : ""; }), and the switch it back for the end user: .replace('.', ',').replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".")